# Python auto escape in lists

Tags: python, string, escaping, backslash

Is there a way to prevent the auto escape of *\* in lists?
Because when I try to *print* or use *writelines* to write a list content in a file, all of the back slashes get escaped.

Comment: Can you please reduce this to *a small sample* of code that reproduces your issue?

Comment: And please keep it to **one issue** per question.

Comment: I don't know where the auto escape happens so I added the complete code of this

Comment: You can't narrow it down by a little debugging? Also, can you include the expected output as well as the actual output you are getting?

Comment: I think I have this problem since I used the *.encode("utf-8")* because this doesn't happen when you print or convert something to a string

Comment: I suspect you are getting confused by the output of `repr()`. If you are printing *containers* (such as a list, tuple, or dictionary), then the contents are always represented with `repr()`; this produces strings that can, insofar possible, be pasted into a Python script again. This includes showing the contents of strings using escape sequences for non-ASCII, non-printable characters and backslashes.

Comment: So how can I prevent this, mostly when using writelines?

Comment: By unwrapping the content from the container; if it is a list, loop over the list and write that data, not the list object itself. `writelines()` happens to do exactly that; take a sequence and write each value from that list to the file.

Comment: Well I am using file.writelines(sideStrings[0]) but it is still happening, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code you posted doesn't run.  I paste into a shell, and I get this error: NameError: name 'sideStrings' is not defined.  Please post code that runs, and maybe people would try to answer your question.

Comment: @Marcono1234: that looks like you are writing *individual codepoints*, use `file.write()` for a single value, not `file.writelines()`.

Comment: Are you sure? also what do you mean by *individual codepoints*? And I said something wrong, this whole thing also happens without using a container

Comment: I am really sorry but I can't figure out the problem, it is not, that the function calls itself to add more strings, also this auto escape is not happening with normal print or writelines(), could it maybe be caused by the encoding?

Comment: Well sorry figured out my mistake, it seems really to be a problem with the list, do you know how I can fix this problem or use a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can undo the `repr()` here with `ast.literal_eval()` *(requires `import ast`)*, I saw that in another post and I hope this is the best way to solve it.